# c# query not updating database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to update the `LastUpdOn` column in my database table with the following code:

```
if (FileImgsave.HasFile == true)
{
    string imgfile = Path.GetFileName(FileImgsave.PostedFile.FileName);

    // FileImgsave.SaveAs("Images/" + imgfile);
    FileImgsave.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + imgfile));

    sqlCon.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Advertisement SET Item = @item, ImgPath = @image, Name = @name WHERE AdvID = '" + AdsTb.Text + "'";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameTb.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", imgfile);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", "~/Images/" + imgfile);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand("UpdTime", sqlCon);
    sqlCmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // string qry = "UPDATE AdvertisementTest SET Item='" + itemTb.Text + "' WHERE AdvertisementID='"+AdsTb.Text+"' AND ImgPath='"+ImageTb.Text+"'";

    sqlCon.Close();

    FillGridView();

    LitMsg.Text = "Update successfully!";
    Clear();
    ButSave.Enabled = true;
}
```

UpdTime query is below

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[UpdTime]
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE Advertisement
    SET LastUpdOn = GETDATE()
END
```

I've checked my database and the `LastUpdOn` column hasn't been updated, so it's still `NULL`.

Comment: On the surface, the code you've given looks like it *should* work. Have you attached a debugger and stepped through to see if it's all actually running? (i.e. that you're not hitting an exception somewhere which means that it's not getting to `sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();`)

Comment: I think you should check connection for your sqlCmd2 it may be some other server/database so it was working but your are checking at other server/database.

Comment: Your first statement should really use **parameters** for **ALL** values in the query! Like this: `  cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Advertisement SET Item = @item, ImgPath = @image, Name = @name WHERE AdvID = @AdvId;");` - why use parameters for the `SET` values - but not for the value in the `WHERE` clause?? .....

Comment: As a sidenote, do you really want to update the `LastUpdOn` for all rows in your stored procedure or just the one you've just updated in your previous query? (in that case, why not just do it in 1 query?)